# Trim function for exceptions

Tags: php, trim

As you know with second parameter of [trim](http://php.net/trim) (same as [ltrim](http://php.net/ltrim), [rtrim](http://php.net/rtrim)) you can add exact symbols to by trimmed.

For example I have string:

```
$myStr = '(!@STRING$)';
```

If I use `trim` for symbols `()!$` I'll get:

```
$myStr = trim($myStr,'()!');
echo $myStr; // Output: @STRING$
```

Now I want to trim all symbols excepting some symbols, for example `@$`:

```
$myStr = new_trim($myStr,'@$');
echo $myStr; // Output: @STRING$
```

I can **explode my needle to array** and **loop on string** from start till my symbol will be in array, and same from back, but it not looks good solution.

Comment: You want to remove every symbol except `@` and `$` from the beginning and the end of your string? Did I understand that correctly? If so, regular expressions are your best option, I think.

Comment: Couldn't you remove them all, then restore some of them back?

Comment: Please provide a better example for why `trim($foo, '()!')` isn't sufficient. In your example the result of that and `new_trim($foo, '@$')` is exactly the same, so why would you need a new function at all?

Comment: One would assume its because Narek doesn't always know what symbols will be in the string and therefore wants to remove any except the $ and @, however if Narek could reply it would help :)

Comment: @TillHelge yes fullybaked is right, I just know symbols what I need and don' know what there are now.

Comment: @CORRUPT I don't know what to remove. Just know what to leave.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To have an exclusion list rather than inclusion you would need to use a preg_replace rather than trim.  trim only accepts a string of the symbols you want to remove

This would do what you want in your question, you just need to add other symbols you want to keep inside the `[]` remember to escape any that have meaning in a regex

```
preg_replace('/[^@\$\w]/', '', $input);
```

Edit: To only remove your symbols from the front and back of the string

```
preg_replace('/^[^\$@]+|[^\$@]+$/', '', $input);
```

To pass a variable of symbols to keep you can do this

```
$symbols = '@$';

preg_replace('/^[^'.preg_quote($symbols).']+|[^'.preg_quote($symbols).']+$/', '', $input);
```

Comment: It will, however, replace them in the entire string, not only at the beginning and end.

Comment: Amended to handle that case :)

Comment: Thanks for answer! Does this will work for any symbol? I mean is there any "system" symbols in regex (for example `^,[..․`) what will break it, or `\` at start cover them all?

Comment: No theres nothing weird.  Just put a `\` before any symbol that has meaning in a regex (you can use the documentation to check which ones)

Comment: But problem is what I don't know what symbols will be added. I want to create function for all cases. This will not work, right? `preg_replace('/^[^\\'.$symbols.']+|[^\\'.$symbols.']+$/', '', $input);`